# Geofire querying the most recent data from certain location

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm using Firebase and Geofire to query data on my iOS project, and I'm stuck big time to figure out a way to go about this certain problem. How would you retrieve the 10 most recent data on a certain location. As far as I know, there's no such thing as `queryByOrder` as Firebase API does... and retrieving all data at a certain coordinate and sorting doesn't seem to be efficient since my app allows thousands of data at the same location. Any suggestions?

Comment: The Firebase Database API only allows you to order/filter on a single property in a query. GeoFire already does something quite magical by allowing you to query on two values (latitude and longitude). It does not support ordering/filtering by yet another value, like recency in your case.

Comment: Would you suggest any work around? I really need this function for my app to work.